# How to output length of string in ARM Assembly in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, raspberry-pi4

I'm creating a program to use an external file called `String_Length()` to output the length of a user's string input (e.g "Cat in the hat").

After I enter the string, I keep getting a segmentation error. I would like to know what exactly I'm doing wrong in this program. The `String_Length.s` works fine, just need to know what's wrong in my main function. Any help is much appreciated.

```
.data
 szEnter:   .asciz "Enter STRING: "
 szLength:  .asciz "STRING LENGTH: "
 strLen:    .word 0
 szString:  .skip 12
 endl:      .byte 10

 .text
       .global _start   @ Provide program starting address to Linker

_start:
@ ENTER STRING
ldr r0, =szEnter    @ Load address of r0 into szString
bl putstring        @ Display the string to the terminal

@ READ-IN STRING DATA
ldr r0, =szString   @ Load address of r0 into szString
mov r1, #12     @ Load address of r1 into 12 bytes
bl getstring        @ Read a string of characters terminated by a null

@ COUNT LENGTH OF STRING
ldr r0, =szString   @ Load address of r0 into szString
bl string_Length    @ Counts the characters in the string

@ OUTPUT LENGTH OF STRING
ldr r0, =szLength   @ Load address of r0 into szLength
bl putstring        @ Display the string to the terminal
ldr r0, =strLen     @ Load address of r0 into strLen
bl putstring        @ Display the string to the terminal

@ Newline
ldr r0, =endl
bl putch

mov r0, #0  @ Exit Status code set to 0 indicates "normal completion"
mov r7, #1  @ Service command code (1) will terminate this program
svc 0       @ Issue Linux command to terminate program

.end        @ Issue Linux command to terminate program
```

Comment: what does the disassembly show?  is the address to strLen aligned for example?

Comment: Oh.I see r0 should have the address of the string.  I immediately over-wrote it in the subroutine. Thank you!

Comment: well I would still be careful with the alignment of strLen if you want to do word accesses.

Comment: *Load address of r0 into szString*  - it is the other way round, actually.. And why 12 in ".skip 12"?